# How to kill more than one process in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to kill some of Apache server process in Linux.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you have pid of the processes that want to kill then use `kill` command.

```
kill pid1 [pid2 pid3 ...]
```

And if this doesn't kill the processes you can add `-9` flag to `kill` command to forcefully kill the processes like

```
kill -9 pid1 [pid2 pid3 ...]
```

To get the pid of the process you can use `ps` command as

```
ps ax | grep apache
```

first column of output is the pid of the process.

Comment: I would recommend that you *don't* use -9 as a default. You should kill the process 'normally' and let it shut down in an organised fashion. Only if it doesn't respond should you use -9

Comment: isn't it `kill -9 pid1 pid2 pid3` ? People might be confused by the brackets...

Comment: what about?
`for pid in 'ps aux | grep apache | awk {"print $2"}'; do kill -9 $pid; done;`

change ' with `

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
killall apache2
```

if you want to kill all apache processes.

```
ps aux | grep apache2
```

will show the apache servers with their PID. Then you can kill selectively:

```
kill -9 pid1 pid5
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the Linux command `killall`. You can kill processes by name and thus do something a little more coarse-grained than using the pid. You can use names or regular expressions (with the `-r` option) to specifiy your victims.

Use a normal `SIGTERM` (default) to begin with. This will let the processes catch the signal, and if they're well-behaved they'll clear up/close resources properly and then exit. Only if the processes don't respond should you use the `SIGKILL` (-9) signal.